# ImportError related to sqlite3 on MacOs

Tags: python, macos, sqlite, pycharm, plotly

I'm trying to use a new package (plotly-resampler) in some python code I've developed under pycharm 2020.3 CE running on MacOs Monterey 12.6 and I get this error when I try to import from the package:

```
from plotly_resampler import FigureResampler
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jason/VirtualEnvironments/imu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/plotly_resampler/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .figure_resampler import FigureResampler, FigureWidgetResampler
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jason/VirtualEnvironments/imu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/plotly_resampler/figure_resampler/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .figure_resampler import FigureResampler
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jason/VirtualEnvironments/imu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/plotly_resampler/figure_resampler/figure_resampler.py", line 21, in <module>
    from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jason/VirtualEnvironments/imu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyter_dash/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import jupyter_dash.comms
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jason/VirtualEnvironments/imu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyter_dash/comms.py", line 2, in <module>
    import IPython
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jason/VirtualEnvironments/imu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from .terminal.embed import embed
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jason/VirtualEnvironments/imu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/terminal/embed.py", line 15, in <module>
    from IPython.core.interactiveshell import DummyMod, InteractiveShell
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jason/VirtualEnvironments/imu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 73, in <module>
    from IPython.core.history import HistoryManager
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jason/VirtualEnvironments/imu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/history.py", line 11, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): Symbol not found: (_sqlite3_enable_load_extension)
  Referenced from: '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-39-darwin.so'
  Expected in: '/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib'
```

I've seen related issues in google searches, but I can't figure out how to fix this.